# Is it bad practice to specialize template method to implement strategy pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, strategy-pattern

I came across a class that implements a kind of "strategy pattern" with a concrete implementation defined inside the main class as a template method.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct ObjA {
    int a = 123;
};

struct ObjB {
    int b = 456;
};

class Algo {
public:
    void stratA(const ObjA& obj) {
        strat<ObjA>(obj);
    };
    void stratB(const ObjB& obj) {
        strat<ObjB>(obj);
    };
private:
    template<typename T>
    void strat(const T& obj) {
        std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
        print<T>(obj);
        std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    void print(const T& obj);
};

template<>
void Algo::print(const ObjA& obj) {
    std::cout << obj.a << std::endl;
}


template<>
void Algo::print(const ObjB& obj) {
    std::cout << obj.b << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    Algo algo;
    ObjA a;
    ObjB b;
    algo.stratA(a);
    algo.stratB(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it a known pattern of should this be considered bad practice?

The strategies and their usage being known at compile time, the main goal I guess is to avoid indirection and hide template abstraction to the user of `Algo` class.

Comment: Aside: you could make `strat ` public, `stratA` and `stratB` aren't needed because template arguments can be deduced